# Problem with pr2_2dnav tutorial

Tags: ros, tutorial, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i'm trying to follow the [pr2_2dnav tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_2dnav) but I found that when  I execute the command `roslaunch pr2_2dnav pr2_2dnav.launch` it says:

```
[pr2_2dnav.launch] is neither a launch file in package [pr2_2dnav] nor is [pr2_2dnav] a launch file name
```

I used `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pr2-2dnav` in order to obtain the package.

What could generate this problem?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205061/problem-with-pr2_2dnav-tutorial/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_navigation_apps/blob/d97e2a926fc120ccba62a78fe5433f036738e679/pr2_2dnav/CMakeLists.txt) for `pr2_2dnav` for Hydro, it would appear that the launch file is not installed (the build script is missing an `install(..)` rule). That would result in the error message you quoted.

You can check this by doing a `ls -al /opt/ros/hydro/share/pr2_2dnav/` and then look for the `pr2_2dnav.launch` file in the listing. It will most likely not be there.

If the file is missing, please log an issue on the `pr2_navigation_apps` [issue tracker](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_navigation_apps/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-17**:
under this directory is only a `cmake` folder and a `package.xml` file, there are no more files/folders. Should I log an issue then?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-17**:
Yes, file an issue and please add a link to this question to the issue.

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2015-03-17**:
Thanks for bringing this up. I've fixed it and re-released it. See: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/7546

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-18**:
By the way, it is possible to use this library for the turtlebot? or it is only for PR2 robot?

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2015-03-18**:
Please open a new question if this one is answered.